# Implementing a vertical icon tool bar in Java Swing

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I'm trying to implement a vertical tool bar on my paint app with window builder [swing] , but I can't put more than one tool items on it because they keep staying side to side to each other.

And I can't find a place to change the tool item appearance to a icon of my choice.

Here is the part of the code I have tried

```
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(shell, SWT.FLAT | SWT.RIGHT);
    toolBar.setBounds(0, 0, 43, 319);
    formToolkit.adapt(toolBar);
    formToolkit.paintBordersFor(toolBar);

    ToolItem tltmTool = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
    tltmTool.setText("tool 1");

    ToolItem tltmTool_1 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
    tltmTool_1.setText("tool 2");
```

if anyone have a tip I would appreciate it

Comment: This is not Swing and looks more to be SWT? Are you sure that your [tag:swing] question tag is correct? Mind that you don't want to attract the wrong experts to your question.

Comment: well when i create my project in the window builder , it didn't explicit said swing or awt or swt , but my final project is suposed to use swing  and the teacher instructed us to use windowbuilder to make it easier so i supposed it was swing, but if you say so i'll remove the tag 
thanks

Comment: What WindowBuilder are you using? If it's supposed to be Swing, perhaps you're using the wrong one?

Comment: Honestly, in my opinion it's much easier to write a Swing application *without* a GUI builder.

Comment: i'm using the WindowBuilder pro for eclipse neon that i downloaded from
[link]https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Comment: Matheus, it looks like that window builder can be used to create Swing or SWT GUI's, and so perhaps you need to adjust its settings so that it is creating a Swing GUI for you. But having said that, I'm 100% with @ostrichofevil and find it much easier to just create my GUI's by hand. I like having full control over the process.

Comment: Yea , i'm kinda realizing it by now... @HovercraftFullOfEels
i managed to set to a vertical tool bar without the GUI help but don't know how to set an icon to a tool.

thanks for the tips guys. I'll keep trying here, and if anyone have other tips for me i'm open to it =D

Answer (score 0):

After a little struggle here is the solution i acomplished.

```
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(shell, SWT.FLAT | SWT.RIGHT | SWT.VERTICAL);
    toolBar.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_LIGHT_SHADOW));
    toolBar.setBounds(3, 0, 43, 319);
    formToolkit.adapt(toolBar);
    formToolkit.paintBordersFor(toolBar);

    ToolItem tltmTool = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
    tltmTool.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("C:\\Users\\Magwire\\Pictures\\Icons\\1491427712_mouse-pointer.png"));
    tltmTool.setToolTipText("Ferramenta Seta");

    ToolItem tltmTool_2 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
    tltmTool_2.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("C:\\Users\\Magwire\\Pictures\\Icons\\1491429896_draw-08.png"));
    tltmTool_2.setToolTipText("Ferramenta Deletar");
```

it was like @HovercraftFullOfEels and @ostrichofevil said...
it is easier to set things the way i want without the GUI, and in the end i used it just to give-me the sample code...

Thanks everyone that helped !